# Access Query to Join Two Tables Based Off Closest Time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in access and I need to do a join based off of a common column (dest) and closest time in table B that is equal to or earlier than table A.

Flights  (Table A)

```
ID | dest | land
1  | SUN  | 1/1/2017 8:52:00 AM
2  | SEA  | 1/1/2017 4:39:00 AM
```

Weather (Table B)

```
ID | dest | time                | vis 
1  | SUN  | 1/1/2017 8:15:00 AM | 10
2  | SUN  | 1/1/2017 8:35:00 AM | 5
3  | SUN  | 1/1/2017 8:55:00 AM | 2
4  | SEA  | 1/1/2017 2:48:00 AM | 7
5  | SEA  | 1/1/2017 3:52:00 AM | 10
6  | SEA  | 1/1/2017 4:49:00 AM | 2
```

Desired Results (Table C)

```
ID | dest | land                | time                | vis
1  | SUN  | 1/1/2017 8:52:00 AM | 1/1/2017 8:35:00 AM | 5
2  | SEA  | 1/1/2017 4:39:00 AM | 1/1/2017 3:52:00 AM | 10
```

I've been stuck on how to join on both the 'dest' AND the closest time. Table A contains ~25,000 rows and Table B ~ 100,000.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT Flights.dest, Flights.land, 
(select time from weather 
    where id = (select top 1 id 
                from weather 
                where dest=flights.dest and time <= flights.land 
                order by time desc)) AS [time], 
(select vis from weather 
    where id = (select top 1 id 
                from weather 
                where dest=flights.dest and time <= flights.land 
                order by time desc)) AS vis
FROM Flights;
```

Alternatively, the same result can be achieved with this query:

```
SELECT Flights.dest, Flights.land, 
weather.time, weather.vis
FROM Flights INNER JOIN weather ON Flights.dest = weather.dest
WHERE weather.time = (
   select top 1 time 
   from weather 
   where dest=flights.dest and time <= flights.land 
   order by time desc);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing these solutions. I tried the first option and was unable to get the query to complete when the 'time <= flights.land' part was included. The query would run, but never complete, even with a small amount of data. Using the second solution with the INNER JOIN it would complete in ~4 mins with a small set of data, but using my full data set after 21 mins it still wasn't complete. Any suggestions on speeding it up, or perhaps a 2-step process? I've indexed the fields used in the query.

Comment: you need an index for the `dest` column in both tables and for the `land` column in the flights table and for the `time` column in the weather table. I assume that the `ID` is the primary key - so no index is required for it